static variables, (memory-gb) in Dart
I have a question about static variables. As far as I know they are never deleted from memory(?). I wanted to ask how correct it is to use the following methods to write clean code. When I go to the colors class in Flutter, we can see that colors are static const. I can use this for colors, but when we use it for string data (or image path) won't we be filling up memory unnecessarily? I don't want to define string data as final and manage it with mixin (or any other method). As far as I understand from the garbage collector, it can be deleted from memory as long as there is no reference. If we create this page in the HomeView page by binding it with part, part-of and making it _ hidden or if we apply another solution, can it be deleted from memory? or does managing string data in this way have much effect on memory? thanks
@immutable
final class AppColor {
  const AppColor._();
  static const Color white = Colors.white;
  static const Color black = Color(0xFF000000);
}

@immutable
final class AppImage {
  const AppImage._();
  static const String logo = 'assets/images/logo.png';
  static const String background = 'assets/images/background.png';
}

@immutable
final class HomeViewKeys {
  const HomeViewKeys._();
  static const emailText = 'Enter Email';
  static const passwordText = 'Enter Password';
  static const appBarTitle = 'Home View';
  static const okButtonText = 'Ok';
  static const cancelButtonText = 'Cancel';
}

or like this:
class _LoginViewState extends State<LoginView> with LoginViewMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const appTitle = 'Welcome to Login';
    const emailText = 'E-mail Address';
    const passwordText = 'Password';
    const buttonText = 'Sign in';
    const forgotText = 'Forgot Password?';
    const registerText = "Don't have an account?";
    const orLoginWith = 'Or login with ';
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          //! Background Image
          Image.asset(ImagePaths.background, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          //! Background Layout
          DecoratedBox(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5))),
          //! Body
          Padding(
            padding: context.paddingLow,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const Spacer(),
                //* logo
                SvgPicture.asset(ImagePaths.logo),
                SizedBox(height: context.lowSize),
                //* title
                const AppTitle(title: appTitle),
                SizedBox(height: context.lowSize),
                //* Email Field
                CustomTextField(controller: emailController, title: emailText),
                //* Password Field
                CustomTextField(
                    controller: passwordController, title: passwordText),
                //* Forgot Password
                const ForgotPassword(forgotText: forgotText),
                //* LoginButton
                CustomButton(function: () {}, title: buttonText),
                const Spacer(),
                //* Divider
                MediumText(text: orLoginWith),
                const Spacer(),
                //* Icons
                Expanded(child: LoginIcons()),
                const Spacer(flex:3),
                //* Register Text
                Expanded(child: RegisterUI(text: registerText)),
                const Spacer(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


const values won't be garbage collected. A value assigned to a static variable can be garbage collected if it is no longer being referenced. For example if you had static Color black = Color(0xFF000000); and then did black = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);, the previous color object could now be garbage collected because it is no longer being referenced by black. As for how much effect this has on memory, my phone has 6GB of RAM or 48 billion bits, dart strings are UTF-16 or 16 bits per code unit.
